# Guice Scala module - No valid constructors

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

I have playframework application written in scala. Problem is when I want to add new module for Silhouette. My module class is very similar to one from [Silhouette example](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-seed/blob/master/app/modules/SilhouetteModule.scala). I can run application trough sbt with simple run command but when I build jar using sbt-assembly and try run it I get:

```
 No valid constructors
    at play.api.inject.Modules$.$anonfun$constructModule$6(Module.scala:155)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
    at play.api.inject.Modules$.constructModule(Module.scala:155)
    at play.api.inject.Modules$.$anonfun$locate$4(Module.scala:127)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:237)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1.foreach(HashSet.scala:321)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:977)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:237)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.AbstractSet.scala$collection$SetLike$$super$map(Set.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.SetLike.map(SetLike.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.SetLike.map$(SetLike.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.AbstractSet.map(Set.scala:51)
    at play.api.inject.Modules$.locate(Module.scala:125)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModule$.loadModules(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:276)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder$.$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$default$9$1(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:30)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.applicationModule(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:102)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:185)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:137)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:51)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:25)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and solved it by adding configuration as a parameter to constructor, for some reason it searches for constructor with configuration, not sure if this is the same issue as yours.

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;

@Inject
public TradeClearingWorkboardGuiceModule(Environment environment, Config configuration) {

}
```